# how to get value which not in table 2

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

how to get table_1 id which is not in table_2
my table look like this type.
**table_1**

```
---------------------------------------------
|  id      |    user                        |
---------------------------------------------
|   1      |    Jack                        |
---------------------------------------------
|   2      |    John                        |
---------------------------------------------
```

**table_2**

```
------------------------------------------
|  web_id      |    website              |
------------------------------------------
|   2          |   Facebook              |
------------------------------------------
|   3          |   Google+               |
------------------------------------------
```

i want to **codeigniter** query

```
$this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from("table_1");
        $this->db->where_not_in('id', "table_2.web_id");
        return $this->db->get();
```

Comment: How are these 2 tables related?

Comment: i think id and web_id

Comment: i have added queries for both ways below

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 SELECT id
 FROM table_1
 WHERE id NOT IN
 (
       SELECT web_id FROM table_2 WHERE 1
 );
```

Using CodeIgniter Active Records the query will be as follows

```
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->where('id NOT IN (SELECT web_id FROM table_2 WHERE 1)', NULL, FALSE);
  $query = $this->db->get('table_1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do it (depending on what flavour of SQL you're using you may have to adjust syntax slightly):

```
SELECT id
FROM table_1
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT web_id FROM table_2)
```

However, I don't see what use this is. There's no identifiable link between the two tables, so knowing that there's an `id` of 1 in table_1 but no `web_id` of 1 in table_2 doesn't seem like a useful piece of information.

Comment: yes its core query but when i am try it on codeigniter this query can you tell me what wrong in this query `$this->db->select("*");
  $this->db->from($this->_table);
  $this->db->where_not_in('id', $this->_tuple.".tuple_regexs_id");
  return $this->db->get();`

Comment: @user2846831 I don't code in PHP, so no I can't tell you what's wrong with that. If it's a problem with PHP code that you're having then you need to make that clear in the question (and make sure you include the relevant parts of the code!), because right now it reads as "What is the SQL to do this?"

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.id
from table_1 t1
left join table_2 t2 on t1.id = t2.web_id
where t2.web_id is null
```